# Django view return error with jQuery post

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I have the following JavaScript jQuery AJAX call to a Django view:

```
$.post('/accounts/ajax/user_verification/', data)
    .done( user_verification_cb )
    .fail( console.log('user_verification POST failed') );
```

... the Django view:

```
@json_view
@login_required
def user_verification(request):

    value = unicode(request.POST['user_list'])
    user_list = json.loads(value)

    v_users = []

    for user_id in user_list:

        v_users.append(user_id)

    j_v_users = json.dumps(v_users)
    result = dict(user_list = j_v_users)

    print (__name__ + ', user_verification, j_v_users = ' + j_v_users)

    return result
```

I get the following output (j_v_users variable):

```
accounts.ajax, user_verification, j_v_users = ["42"]
```

At the JavaScript, the ".fail()" promise is always invokated. Moreover, I always get the following exception with the Django development server:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 50211)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 593, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/home/rtubio/repositories/satnet-release-1/WebServices/__v_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 150, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 651, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 704, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I know that maybe this exception might be an internal error of the Django development server. However, I do not know if this is provoking the problem with the return to the jQuery $.post().

Comment: 1) you're doing a post without sending csrf_token, so it should definitely fail. 2) Looking at the error traceback it complains about something else - is there a possibility you are sending a very large amount if data?

Comment: I am using AJAX and I have configured the jQuery to automatically add the csrf_token to every call (base.html): <script type="text/javascript">$.ajaxSetup({data: { csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' },}); </script>